# How to update my Bokeh Legend to reflect Categorical Variable in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with Bokeh that highlights the points in clusters I found. I have the dropdown menu working, but now I want to be able to visualize another categorical variable by color: Noun Class with levels of Masc, Fem, and Neuter. The problem is that the legend won't update when I switch which cluster I'm visualizing. Furthermore, if the first cluster I visualize doesn't have all 3 noun classes in it, the code starts treating all the other clusters I try to look at as (incorrectly) having that first cluster's noun class. For example, if Cluster 0 is the default and only has Masc points, all other clusters I look at using the dropdown menu are treated as only having Masc points even if they have Fem or Neuter in the actual DF.

My main question is this: how can I update the legend such that it's only attending to the respective noun classes of 'Curr'

Here's some reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook, save, push_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, DateRangeSlider, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS 
from bokeh.layouts import row,column,layout
import random
import numpy as np
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.palettes import Colorblind
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

#Generate reproducible DF
noun_class_names = ["Masc","Fem","Neuter"]

x = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(100)]
y = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(100)]

rand_clusters = [str(random.randint(0,10)) for i in range(100)]
noun_classes = [random.choice(noun_class_names) for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_coord':x, 'y_coord':y,'noun class':noun_classes,'cluster labels':rand_clusters})

df.loc[df['cluster labels'] == '0', 'noun class'] = 'Masc' #ensure that cluster 0 has all same noun class to illustrate error


clusters = [str(i) for i in range(len(df['cluster labels'].unique()))]

cols1 = df#[['cluster labels','x_coord', 'y_coord']]
cols2 = cols1[cols1['cluster labels'] == '0']

Overall = ColumnDataSource(data=cols1)
Curr = ColumnDataSource(data=cols2)


#plot and the menu is linked with each other by this callback function
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""
var f = cb_obj.value
sc.data['x_coord']=[]
sc.data['y_coord']=[]
for(var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
    if (source.data['cluster labels'][i] == f){
        sc.data['x_coord'].push(source.data['x_coord'][i])
        sc.data['y_coord'].push(source.data['y_coord'][i])
        sc.data['noun class'].push(source.data['noun class'][i])
        sc.data['cluster labels'].push(source.data['cluster labels'][i])
    }
}   
sc.change.emit();
""")

menu = Select(options=clusters, value='0', title = 'Cluster #')  # create drop down menu

bokeh_p=figure(x_axis_label ='X Coord', y_axis_label = 'Y Coord', y_axis_type="linear",x_axis_type="linear") #creating figure object 

mapper = factor_cmap(field_name = "noun class", palette = Colorblind[6], factors = df['noun class'].unique()) #color mapper for noun classes

bokeh_p.circle(x='x_coord', y='y_coord', color='gray', alpha = .5, source=Overall) #plot all other points in gray
bokeh_p.circle(x='x_coord', y='y_coord', color=mapper, line_width = 1, source=Curr, legend_group = 'noun class') # plotting the desired cluster using glyph circle and colormapper

bokeh_p.legend.title = "Noun Classes"


menu.js_on_change('value', callback) # calling the function on change of selection
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
show(layout(menu,bokeh_p), notebook_handle=True)
```

Thanks in advance and I hope you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imma keep it real with y'all... The code works how I want now and I'm not entirely sure what I did. What I think I did was reset the noun classes in the Curr data source and then update the legend label field after selecting a new cluster to visualize and updating the xy coords. If anyone can confirm or correct me for posterity's sake I would appreciate it :)

Best!

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, Figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, push_notebook, show, output_file, save
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.palettes import Colorblind
from bokeh.layouts import layout, gridplot, column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, CustomJS, Select, DateRangeSlider, Legend, LegendItem
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

#Generate reproducible DF
noun_class_names = ["Masc","Fem","Neuter"]

x = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(100)]
y = [random.randint(0,50) for i in range(100)]

rand_clusters = [str(random.randint(0,10)) for i in range(100)]
noun_classes = [random.choice(noun_class_names) for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_coord':x, 'y_coord':y,'noun class':noun_classes,'cluster labels':rand_clusters})

df.loc[df['cluster labels'] == '0', 'noun class'] = 'Masc' #ensure that cluster 0 has all same noun class to illustrate error

clusters = [str(i) for i in range(len(df['cluster labels'].unique()))]

cols1 = df#[['cluster labels','x_coord', 'y_coord']]
cols2 = cols1[cols1['cluster labels'] == '0']

Overall = ColumnDataSource(data=cols1)
Curr = ColumnDataSource(data=cols2)



#plot and the menu is linked with each other by this callback function
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""
var f = cb_obj.value
sc.data['x_coord']=[]
sc.data['y_coord']=[]
sc.data['noun class'] =[]
for(var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
    if (source.data['cluster labels'][i] == f){
        sc.data['x_coord'].push(source.data['x_coord'][i])
        sc.data['y_coord'].push(source.data['y_coord'][i])
        sc.data['noun class'].push(source.data['noun class'][i])
        sc.data['cluster labels'].push(source.data['cluster labels'][i])
    }
}

sc.change.emit();
bokeh_p.legend.label.field = sc.data['noun class'];



""")

menu = Select(options=clusters, value='0', title = 'Cluster #')  # create drop down menu

bokeh_p=figure(x_axis_label ='X Coord', y_axis_label = 'Y Coord', y_axis_type="linear",x_axis_type="linear") #creating figure object 

mapper = factor_cmap(field_name = "noun class", palette = Colorblind[6], factors = df['noun class'].unique()) #color mapper- sorry this was a thing that carried over from og code (fixed now)

bokeh_p.circle(x='x_coord', y='y_coord', color='gray', alpha = .05, source=Overall)

bokeh_p.circle(x = 'x_coord', y = 'y_coord', fill_color = mapper, line_color = mapper, source = Curr, legend_field = 'noun class')


bokeh_p.legend.title = "Noun Classes"



menu.js_on_change('value', callback) # calling the function on change of selection
bokeh.io.output_notebook(INLINE)
show(layout(menu,bokeh_p), notebook_handle=True)
```